# Sqlite glob on a function index

Tags: sqlite

Using the latest SQLite, I can make an index on a deterministic function of a text field (e.g. MYFUNC(MyCol)). But whenever I try to do a glob search on this, e.g.

```
select * from myTable where MYFUNC(MyCol) glob 'Z*'
```

it does not appear to use the index, but instead slowly calls MYFUNC on every row in the table. According to https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html you cannot use overloaded built-in functions in glob expressions with an index, but it doesn't say you can't use non-overloading custom function. Is this actually another limitation, or am I doing something wrong?

(it seems like a very common thing to want to do, e.g. to allow searching on name fields without sensitivity to accents, prefixes, etc, by using a MYFUNC that standardizes field formatting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom function could be making the index useless. Even if it theoretically doesn't, I wouldn't expect sqlite to be able to figure that out.

Actually, the docs you link say exactly that:

> There are many conditions on this use:
>   1. The left-hand side of the LIKE or GLOB operator must be the name of an indexed column with TEXT affinity.
>   2. [...]

So applying *any* function to the column will prevent sqlite from utilizing the index.

The way to do what you're trying to do is to have an extra column in your table: call it `MyCol_clean` or something. Make sure to update it whenever `MyCol` changes (you can do this with triggers).

With the new column added (creating an index on there instead, of course), you can efficiently search your table, with the added bonus of not having to evaluate `MYFUNC` at all during queries.

Comment: OK, thanks, must have misunderstood. I am of course using an extra column at the moment, I thought the new ability to add indices on functions might be able to save the extra file space of the otherwise rather redundant column - but it seems not. I don't see in principle why a text function of a text column could not be indexed and globbed just like an original text column; you seem to be able to use the function on the column name to use the index in most other contexts.

Comment: Because your text function may not return values that are ordered the same way as the original text column. An index is very fragile -- you have to make sure your queries are written in such a way that they can use them.